# Typescript + RequireJs + AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, typescript

In my front-end I want to use typescript with requireJs and AngularJs

I got typescript working with angularjs, but when I want to add requireJs nothing is working anymore. I hope someone can help me here :)

This is basically my structure:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/yGVnqWK.jpg]

In my index file i am refering the main file as my requireJs starting point

```
</script><script src="/components/requirejs/require.js" data-main="/js/main">
```

This is my main.ts

```
///<reference path="types/collection.d.ts"/>

require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js/',
    paths: {
        angular: '/components/angular/angular',
        angularRoute: '/components/angular-route/angular-route'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {'exports': 'angular'},
        'angularRoute': ['angular']
    },
    priority: [
        'angular'
    ]
});

require( [
    'angular',
    'app/appsetup'
], function(angular, app) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $html = $('html');
        angular.bootstrap($html, [app.app['name']]);
    });
});
```

Last but not least my appsetup file, where i am loading my app:

```
///<reference path="../types/collection.d.ts"/>
/// <amd-dependency path="angular"/>

import controller = require("./../controllers/home/index");
import angular = require("angular");

export var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
                        .controller('app.controllers.home.index', controller.HomeController);

return app;
```

Also Webstorm underlines angular in the require statement and says that it cant find it.
Currently I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the de......0)

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong? Or do you have maybe some links to pages, where I can see how you can develop with these 3 technologies for large projects?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When typescript compiles it creates the define() function (for either requirejs or commonjs) based on the presence of either import or export. But notice that import and export work only on typescript modules not simple js files.
You can do something like this

```
import myimportmodule = require("myimportmodule");
```

Where your import module was

```
export module myimportmodule
{
   export class Test
   {}
}
```

And you can't do something like this.

```
import angular = require("angular");
```

simply because angular.js is not a typescript module.

look at the code below

```
/**
 * Created by Costa on 4/19/2014.
 */
///<reference path="../ts_references/reference.ts"/>


///<amd-dependency path="angular"/>

//register controllers

import ImportMainCtrl = require("controllers/import/importMainCtrl");
export module Controllers
{

    var angular:ng.IAngularStatic = require("angular");
    var ControllersAM:ng.IModule;
    ControllersAM = angular.module('controllers', []);
    ControllersAM.controller(ImportMainCtrl);
}
```

Notice this line?

```
///<amd-dependency path="angular"/>
```

it will add a dependency into the define function so the js file looks like this:

```
/**
* Created by Costa on 4/19/2014.
*/
///<reference path="../ts_references/reference.ts"/>
define(["require", "exports", "controllers/import/importMainCtrl", "angular"], function(require, exports, ImportMainCtrl) {
    (function (Controllers) {
        var angular = require("angular");
        var ControllersAM;
        ControllersAM = angular.module('controllers', []);
        ControllersAM.controller(ImportMainCtrl);
    })(exports.Controllers || (exports.Controllers = {}));
    var Controllers = exports.Controllers;
});
//# sourceMappingURL=controllers.js.map
```

Thats why you need this

```
var angular:ng.IAngularStatic = require("angular");
```

To access angular functionality.
Hope that helps.
Edited----
Or you can do the following in either angular.d.ts or another .d.ts file if you really want to import it like this

```
declare module 'angular'{
    export var angular:ng.IAngularStatic;
}
```

this will create an external module declaration with the var angular inside and export it.

Comment: thx. but I found on my server-side code this: ´import express = require('express');´ The only thing I added was a reference to a a express.d.ts file. Why can I do it there and not with angular. The only difference is that I compile my server-side code with commonJs option and the clientside one with amd

Comment: Edited the post and added the possibility to require angular

Comment: Hi Costa, I might be a bit thick, but I am confused by your post.  I have the same error as the OP, but cannot follow your answer.  Is there more than one solution in this answer?  (i.e., are you describing multiple options how this problem may be resolved?)

Comment: Try this reference, there's a github repo. 
http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/typescript-amd-with-requirejs-tutorial/